# unable to merge android manifest +admob Error

Tags: unity-game-engine

after I add Admob, I start seeing this issue. I don't know what's the problem. I tried to search about it here, but I couldn't find any working solution. Can you help please?

Comment: Please add details on what you mean by `issue` and `add AdMob`.

Comment: Please add more information, as it stands your question is not anwerable. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information on how to ask a proper question. At the very least include the error message and the code responsible for the error